# Android App & dropdown MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, list, drop-down-menu

need a lil help.

Taking this example ( http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp ), I want to make the same but if you see this part of the code:

```
form 
 select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)/select
 option value=""> Select a person: /option 
 option value="1"> Peter Griffin /option
 option value="2"> Lois Griffin /option 
 option value="3"> Glenn Quagmire /option 
 option value="4"> Joseph Swanson /option 
 /select 
/form
```

Is a static list with values given already.

I want to take out the name values from my DB and create a dropdown list with the array.

My problem is that I already make it in php but android app can't read php, so what can I do?

Comment: use it as a point of data a and send the data back to the app in a `JSON` format that's readable by the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing:

Suppose $data is an array contains the values for drop down.

now,you can do this:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc();
$data=$row//array containing the values for drop down.
return json_encode($data);
```